# Helm Template predifined Array Iterate for configmap

Tags: spring, go, kubernetes-helm, helm3

Hi we have listenerProcessor array in values.yaml like below

```
listenerProcessor:
- name: "nbi-sbi"
  port: 99
  allowedPath:
  - "/sbi/test"
  - "/sbi/test123"
```

for this we need to merge our predefined set of listenerProcessor array which is not exposed through values.yaml , which something like this below

```
listenerProcessor:
- name: nbinorc
  port: 9910
  allowedPath: 
  - /nbi/norc/tmf641/v4/orders/
  - /nbi/norc/tmf645/v4/serviceQualification
- name: nbiuiv
  port: 9920
  allowedPath: 
  - /nbi/uiv/tmf640/v4/services/
```

so to merge this two as single property and iterate it over , defined a variable in _helper.tpl

```
{{- define "nifi.listener-processor.spec" -}}
listenerProcessor:
- name: nbinorc
  port: 9910
  allowedPath: 
  - /nbi/norc/tmf641/v4/orders/
  - /nbi/norc/tmf645/v4/serviceQualification
- name: nbiuiv
  port: 9920
  allowedPath: 
  - /nbi/uiv/tmf640/v4/services/
{{ toYaml .Values.listenerProcessor.ports }}
{{- end -}}
```

Now i need to iterate it over **.name** & **.port** in NOTES.txt but its giving error " <.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface {}".
In NOTES.txt i have this

```
{{- $listenerProcessor := (include "nifi.listener-processor.spec" . ) }}
{{- range $index, $element :=  fromYaml $listenerProcessor }}
  {{ .name }}
  {{ .port }}
{{- end }}
```

when i just print **$element** & **$index** those values its showing below output

```
NOTES:
$NIFI_CONF_DIRECTORY_PATH/extensions directory"
  
 [map[allowedPath:[/nbi/norc/tmf641/v4/orders/ /nbi/norc/tmf645/v4/serviceQualification] name:nbinorc port:9910] map[allowedPath:[/nbi/uiv/tmf640/v4/services/] name:nbiuiv port:9920] map[allowedPath:[/sbi/test /sbi/test123] name:nbi-sbi port:99]]
```

listenerProcessor

Answer (score 0):

Got that Working with below code, we need to have another variable and than do pass it for range over

```
{{- $listenerProcessor :=  (include "nifi.listener-processor.spec" . ) }}
{{- $test := fromYaml $listenerProcessor }}
{{- range $index, $element := $test.listenerProcessor }}
  {{ .name }} {{ .port }} {{ .allowedPath }}
{{- end }}
```